# Sgf2dg and Perl: Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)

Tags: perl

As the title of my question suggests, I encountered the following problem:

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)

in line 1416 of [Sgf2Dg.pm](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/REID/Games-Go-Sgf2Dg-4.252/lib/Games/Go/Sgf2Dg.pm)
of the sgf2dg package.
There it says:

```
} elsif (($arg eq '-break') or ($arg eq '-breakList')) {
    my $breaks = '';
    while (@ARGV and
           $ARGV[0] =! m/[\d,]*/) {
        $breaks .= shift @ARGV;
    }
    @{$option{breakList}} = sort {$a <=> $b} split(/,/, $breaks);
```

Therefore I suppose the problem has something to do with the pattern match `=! m/[\d,]*/`, but I don't know enough `perl` to deal with this myself, nor enough to present you with a simple MWE :(

---

I have installed sgf2dg and it runs without a problem. I can use all the options except for the `-break` one, but that's the one I want. On Linux terminal:

> sgf2dg -break 0 test.sgf

where `test.sgf` is a typical [smart game format file](http://www.red-bean.com/sgf/). Without the `-break 0` option it runs without any problem.

For your convenience I attach an sgf file here:

```
(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[CGoban:3]ST[2]
RU[Japanese]SZ[19]KM[0.00]
AW[qm][oo][po][qo][ro][op][mq][oq][or]AB[pp][qp][rp][pq][pr]PL[W]
;W[rr]
;B[rs]
;W[rq]
;B[sp]
;W[ps]
;B[qs]
;W[os]
;B[qr]
;W[sq]
;B[sr]
;W[ss])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in the code.

`$ARGV[0] =! m/[\d,]*/` really means `$ARGV[0] = (! m/[\d,]*/)`, i.e. assign the negated result of `m/[\d,]*/` to `$ARGV[0]`. And `m/[\d,]*/` matches against `$_` by default, but `$_` isn't set at that point.

The less-incorrect code would be `$ARGV[0] =~ m/[\d,]*/` (a match of `[\d,]*` against `$ARGV[0]`), but that's semantically wrong: `[\d,]*` always matches, so that condition would be always true.

It looks like it's supposed to check that the argument consists of digits and commas only, for which the correct code would be `$ARGV[0] =~ m/\A[\d,]+\z/`.

---

However, according to the documentation, `-break` only accepts one argument, so that whole block could be replaced by:

```
} elsif (($arg eq '-break') or ($arg eq '-breakList')) {
    my $breaks = shift @ARGV;
    @{$option{breakList}} = sort {$a <=> $b} split(/,/, $breaks);
```

Comment: yes, the `-break` argument should be a list of comma separated numbers, e.g. 12,23,56,112

Comment: @flobo Yes, which is a single argument string. The code is written as if it expects the user to specify `-break 1,2 ,3, 4` or something like that (i.e. `1,2` and `,3,` and `4` as separate arguments).

Comment: I replaced the block with what you suggested and it works without a hitch. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been posted online as a bug report: [rt.cpan.org](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=116213), but the suggested solution to replace one line by

```
my $breaks = shift @ARGV;
```

is unclear, and in any case did not work for me.

---

Anyway, I have installed `sgf2dg` on a new Debian `Buster` distribution with the following steps:

1. Default Install of `sgf2dg`:
   Update the system and use `autoremove` to uninstall unused packages. Then run

   ```
   apt-get install sgf2dg
   apt-get remove sgf2dg
   ```

   `apt` will then mark a couple of packages for `autoremove`, but you want to keep them. Again use `apt` to mark them as manual install.
   Then add

   ```
   apt-get install libfile-slurp-perl
   ```

   because you will need it later.
2. Download and Install the latest version

   Browse [to cpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Games-Go-Sgf2Dg/lib/Games/Go/Sgf2Dg.pm) to download and install the latest version of `sgf2dg`.
   If there is an error with the `Makefile` it may help to delete an empty line with only `' '` in it.
3. Repair the installed Perl File
   Locate the file

   ```
   find / -name Sgf2Dg.pm
   ```

   and repair it as suggested by the above solution. This will repair the `-break` bug in the code.
4. (Optional) Higher Level Commands for Annotating Go Diagrams
   Check the suggestions [here on tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348772/typesetting-go-diagrams-with-sgf2dg).

Comment: Thx for editing. I had not been able to use quotes inside the list.